# A question about the Jacobson radical

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

### Question

$k$ is a field, $A$ is a $k$-algebra with finite $k$-dimension, $J(A)$ is its Jacobson radical.

If $A/J(A) \simeq k^n$ for some $n\geq 1$ , is it true that A has an ideal of $k$-dimension $1$?

Of course  $A/J(A)$ must have an ideal of $k$-dimension $1$, I want to find an ideal in $A$ of $k$-dimension $1$.

---

This question comes from a problem about coalgebra , see 《Hopf algebras and Their Actions on Rings》 6.3.4.

Let $D$ is a non-zero pointed coalgebra with finite $k$-dimension ， then $D$ has a subcoalgebra $E$ with codimension 1.

Proof:  Let $E$  be a maximal proper subcoalgebra of  $D$ , then  $E^{\perp}$   is a minimal non-zero ideal of $D^{*}$.

Using the theorey of coalgebra, one can see that

$$D^{*}/J(D_0) = D^{*}/D_0^{\perp} \simeq (D_0)^{*} \simeq k^n$$

Then the author claims that $E^{\perp}$  must has $k$-dimension 1 , but I cannot prove it.

Comment: $A=0$ is a counterexample. Please specify the restrictions that are necessary here. What is $n$ for example?

Comment: Krull dimension of an ideal?

Comment: I have edited this question.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Sure, there's a Krull dimension of modules, or it could have been something like height or something.  Glad to see it's been resolved now.

Comment: @vegetabledog As a rule of thumb, it is not good to update questions with information that invalidates existing answers.  But don't worry about it this time, since ultimately my existing answer was not able to help fully.  I half-expected you might add finite dimensionality.

Comment: @rschwieb Thank you for your suggestion . I'll avoid this issue next time

Answer (score 1):

Let $I$ be a non-zero minimal ideal of $ A$ (must exist since $dim_k \ A$ is finite) , then  $I=\langle a \rangle $ for some  $a \in A$ . We show that $dim_k \ I=1$ .

Notice that $A/J(A) \simeq k^n $ for some $n\geq 1$ , then simple left A-modules have $k$-dimension 1. Similarly, simple right A-modules have $k$-dimension 1.

$I$ is a non-zero left A-module, then it contains a simple left-submodule $M$ since $dim_k \ I$ is finite .  Suppose that $M=A\{ b \}$ for some $b \in I$, then $b=\sum x_iay_i$ for some $x_i ,y_i\in A$.  Notice that $xb \in kb$  for any $x\in A$ . Consider the ideal $\langle b \rangle$ , then
$$0 \subset \langle b \rangle \subseteq I$$
From the minimality of $I$ , we have $I=\langle b \rangle$ .

Repeat the operation in last paragraph, we can find an element

$$c=\sum u_ibw_i=\sum (u_ib)w_i=\sum (\lambda_ib)w_i=\sum b(\lambda_i w_i)=b(\sum \lambda_i w_i)=bw \in I$$

such that $w\in A$ and   $cx \in kc $ for any $x\in A$  and $I= \langle c \rangle $.

Then we can see that  $I= \langle c \rangle =kc$ , thai is , $dim_k I=1$.

Comment: Does $M=A\{b\}$ refer to generating $M$ with one element?  I think also you can't say $b=x_1ay_1$: when $b\in \langle a\rangle$ you only know $b=\sum x_iay_i$ for some finite sum.

Comment: The proof is not accurate but the idea is correct.  The equations $b=x_1ay_1$ and $c=x_2by_2$ are not generally true.  Instead, we have $b=\sum_i x_iay_i$ and $c=\sum_i w_ibz_i$ for some $x_i,y_i,w_i,z_i\in A$.  The equation $b=x_1ay_1$ is never used and the equation for $c$ can be simplified as follows.  Each $w_ib=\lambda_i b$ for some scalar $\lambda_i\in k$, and so $c=b(\sum_i\lambda_i w_i)$.  We can re-write this as $c=bw$ for some $w\in A$.  Since $cA=kc$ and $Ab=kA$, the proof ends as in the OP: $I=AcA=Ac=Abw=kbw=kc$.

Comment: @rschwieb@Allen Bell  Thank for your corrections.I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since $A$ is finite-dimensional over $\mathsf k$, its Jacobson radical $J=J(A)$ is nilpotent, *i.e.* there is some $m\geq 1$ with $J^m=0$. Let $d \in \mathbb Z_{>0}$ be the minimal such $m$, so that $J^{d-1}\supsetneq J^d=\{0\}$. Now $J^{d-1}$ is a 2-sided ideal in $A$, and the action of $A$ on $J^{d-1}$ factors through $A/J$ by our choice of $d$, and by assumption $A/J\cong \mathsf k^n$.

Let, for $i \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ the element $e_i\in A$ be such that $\{e_i+J: 1\leq i \leq n\}$ are the primitive idempotents of $A/J$ so that $1+J = \sum_{i=1}^n e_i +J$ and $e_ie_j +J= \delta_{ij}+J$ (where $\delta_{ij} = 1$ if $i=j$ and is zero otherwise). Thus if $g \in J^{d-1}\backslash \{0\}$, then
$$
g=1.g.1 = (\sum_{i_1=1}^n e_{i_1}).g.(\sum_{i_2=1}^n e_{i_2}) = \sum_{i_1,i_2} e_{i_1}ge_{i_2}
$$
so there must exist $j_1,j_2 \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that $e_{j_1} g e_{j_2} \neq 0$. Let $r = e_{j_1} g e_{j_2}$ and consider the two-sided ideal $ArA$. Now if $a_1,a_2 \in A$ then $a_1e_{j_1} =\lambda e_{j_1} +b_1$ and $e_{j_2}a_2 = \mu e_{j_2} + b_2$ where $\lambda, \mu \in \mathsf k$ and $b_1,b_2 \in J$. Thus we have
$$
a_1 r a_2 = (a_1e_{j_1})g(e_{j_2} a_2) = (\lambda.e_{j_1}+b_1).g.(\mu.e_{j_2}+b_2)= \lambda\mu (e_{j_1} g e_{j_2}) = \lambda\mu.r
$$
so that $\mathsf k.r$ is a two-sided ideal with $\dim_{\mathsf k}(\mathsf k.r) =1$ as required.